# Count Column Data based on Groupings

Tags: sql, sql-server

so I have this problem. My Database has two tables that look something
like this:

```
    Table A:

    ============================
    Username     Group Number
    ============================
    mike              1
    john              1
    stan              2
    mark              2

    ============================


    Table B:

    ========================================
    Username     FeatureA  FeatureB FeatureC
    ----------------------------------------

    mike           Yes                Yes
    john                      Yes
    stan                      Yes     Yes
    mark           Yes                Yes
    ========================================
```

Tables A and B are joined together by Username and I need something that looks like this:

```
    ============================================
    Group Number  FeatureA   FeatureB   FeatureC
    ============================================

         1         1            1          1
         2         1            1          2
    ============================================
```

Basically I need to count the number of users in each group that have access to each feature.

Comment: `FeatureX` is text type column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT a.`Group Number`, 
       SUM(CASE b.FeatureA WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FeatA, 
       SUM(CASE b.FeatureB WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FeatB, 
       SUM(CASE b.FeatureC WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FeatC 
FROM tableA a JOIN tableB b
ON a.username = b.username
GROUP BY a.`Group Number`
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be grouped by `group number`?

Comment: @PiotrAuguscik: it is... maybe you red the post while I was editing it :)